# Do moderators get and accept flags in order or randomly?

Tags: discussion, flags

Do moderators get flag notifications in the order users have flagged, or do they get them in a random order?

I had flagged a few questions, but they were not accepted as helpful flags in order. Might it be that the moderator is still deciding whether my flag is valid or not? Because in this case, the question I've flagged doesn't make any sense at all.

> [image]

Question Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231810/the-steps-for-deleting-all-the-stackoverflow-posts

Comment: moderators got confused that the question is off-topic or not, leaved to other mod to handle :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not every flag gets handled by a moderator. All flags - except the custom moderator attention one - can be handled automatically by the system. This seems to be the case with your two helpful flags, they were probably marked as helpful when the questions received a close vote.

Other than that, it's completely up to the moderators to decide which flags they'll handle and in which order.

Answer (score 4):

On Stack Overflow, we have from 100 to 800 flags at any given moment in the queue (~2500 items being flagged per day over the last month). These are organized into categories based on the type of flag, and then sorted by the flag weight of the individual who cast the flag. Spam and offensive flags are highlighted above all others, so they draw a lot of attention when cast.

With that many flags, and with multiple moderators processing them, when something is handled can vary significantly. This flag handling rate can fall off significantly during the U.S. late night / early morning hours due to a poor overlap of active moderator times during that part of the day.

Personally, I triage flags based on their urgency. Spam and offensive flags are handled right away, and can have severe penalties, which is why [it's important that those be used properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work/58035#58035). "Not an answer" flags can be easy to process, if obvious, and can sometimes include trolls or spammers that we need to deal with. I tend to turn next to the custom flags, because those can contain more urgent or elaborate situations we need to act on (fights in comments, a ring of spammers, vote fraud, etc.).

Close vote flags (like the one you point out) are my least favorite to handle, and the ones that tend to pile up the most. This is an action that the community should be able to take care of, and in fact many of these are shown only to 10k users and never appear in our tools. It sounds like even more of these will be sent out to the community to handle as part of the upcoming flagging changes, and I look forward to that.

If you really feel that a question needs to be closed and / or deleted quickly, use a custom flag and explain why. Those have greater visibility to us, and the extra information can help us see what you did.

Comment: To summarize, If you want a question looked at quickly either flag it as Jon Skeet or use a custom flag.

Comment: @Jake1164 - Flag weight != reputation.

Comment: @Jake1164 What? Is there a hidden "Jon Skeet flag" somewhere that I don't know of?

Answer (score 1):

The Flags you have used goes to Flag queue, which is handled by 10K + users. The flag with the "Other" option directly goes to Moderator's flag queue. Also the flags which are marked as "Spam" or "Offensive" goes directly to moderator's flag queue.